# How to make a view that only shows content a user has not voted on

Tags: views, rating

I'm working on a project that asks a group of users with a specific role to vote on content produced by users with a different role.

The group who votes is supposed to try and vote on each item, so I'm trying to make a view that will give them pages of the content.

I would like the view to only show the content that they have *not yet voted on*, so when they have voted on all items, nothing is displayed in the view.

Comment: Which module are you using for your voting?

Comment: as far as I know you can simply manage to achieve that via contextual filter of views, and if your voting module has integration with views, there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: If you're using Flags, you can just add a relationship for that flag out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

An effective solution to this problem can be found in http://drupal.org/node/513088.

As suggested by Cthos, one should first set up a "Relationship" in the view setting ("advanced" settings in Drupal 7), then use this relationship as a regular filter (no need for contextual filter here).The proposed procedure is:

```
Relationships
    Node: Votes
        "Require this relationship": no
        "Value type": No filtering
        "Vote tag": Normal vote
        "Restrict to current user": yes
Filters
    (Votes) Votes: Value
        "Relationship": use the one from above
        "Operator": "Is empty (NULL)"
```